# How to update embedded resource (file) at design time

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a text file as an embedded resource & can read it fine during runtime. Now when I want to update this resource, it works fine if I edit the file in Visual Studio and then rebuild BUT if I edit in an external editor eg. notepad then the changes are not seen in Visual Studio.

I have tried cleaning then rebuilding but nothing seems to force an update of the resource file - any ideas?

Comment: Does notepad have permission to save the file?  In other words.  Open file in Notepad, make a change.  Save & close notepad.  Reopen file in notepad.  Can you see the changes there?

Comment: Yes, I see the changes in the altered file when opening with notepad windows explorer, but when opening it in Visual Studio it still shows the old data.

Comment: And if you right click on the file in visual studio and click `open (shell)`?

Answer (score 1):

Argh! I see the problem now. VS copied my original file into the solution folder (the one below the .sln file) and VS is using that file. I was editing the file in the original location from where I created the resource.